# Generic method overloading via implicit class

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

When I try to create an extension for the class via implicit class and overload existing generic method, it fails with compilation error:

```
error: overloaded method value getAs with alternatives:
  (fieldName: String)String <and>
  (i: Int)String
 cannot be applied to (FooField.type)
       r.getAs[String](FooField)
```

While overloading normal (non-generic) method via implicit works fine. Tried on Scala 2.12.10. Link to [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XUbIw8L7RTOvJMVUPplFfA). What am I missing? The code:

```
trait Row {
    // Two overloads for `getAs[T]`
    def getAs[T](i: Int): T
    def getAs[T](fieldName: String): T

    // Two overloads for `get`
    def get(i: Int): String
    def get(fieldName: String): String
}

trait Field {
    def columnName: String
    def columnDescription: String
}
case object FooField extends Field {
    def columnName: String = "Foo"
  def columnDescription: String = "Foo desc"
}

object Implicits {
  implicit class RowEx(val r: Row) extends AnyVal {
    def getAs[T](field: Field): T = r.getAs[T](field.columnName)
    def get(field: Field): String = {
      println(s"RowEx.get: field")
      r.get(field.columnName)
    }
  }
}

object Main {
  import Implicits._
  // Create some instance of `Row`
  val r = new Row {
    def getAs[T](i: Int): T = i.toString.asInstanceOf[T]
    def getAs[T](fieldName: String): T = fieldName.toString.asInstanceOf[T]
    def get(i: Int): String = i.toString
    def get(fieldName: String): String = fieldName
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Call extension method => `RowEx.get`
    println(r.get(FooField))

    // Call extension method => `RowEx.get`
    // Won't compile with compilation error:
    /*
    overloaded method value getAs with alternatives:
      (fieldName: String)String 
      (i: Int)String
     cannot be applied to (FooField.type)
    */
    println(r.getAs[String](FooField))
  }
}
```

Opened a bug: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11810

Comment: It's funny that if you don't specify type parameter then this compiles `r.getAs(FooField)`.

Comment: Bugs should be reported here https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: For `r`, which is instance of `Row`, the method `getAs` can accept either `Int` or `String`. You try to pass `FooField` object which has no implicit conversions to `Int` and `String`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin hmm, that's strange though

Comment: @Duelist But there is implicit conversion from `Row` to `RowEx`, which has method `getAs` accepting `FooField.type <: Field`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I can create a bug, but I'm not sure that it is bug.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan It's very similar to a bug :)

Comment: This is one of those annoying things in Scala when one doesnt know whats happening